# .NET MVC3 HttpRequestValidation & JSON

Tags: json, security, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to MVC3 framework (and .NET overall; Java veteran), so bear with me, but here goes:

Input submitted to a Controller as JSON doesn't seem to be subject to the HttpRequestValidation -- Does that sound right?
I realize if you're receiving data input via JSON you're possibly already doing more work with it, but the Controller Action doesn't seem to necessarily know whether it has JSON data at that point; input values are mapped to parameters just as they would be if they were standard POST params.
Example - I'm asynchronously submitting JSON data to my Controller like the following:

```
    var data = { "title": $titleField.val(), "content": $textArea.val(),
        "location": $location.val()
    };

    $.ajax(submitUrl,
        {
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            complete: function (data) {
                //blah blah
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(data)
        });
    }
```

I then receive the input in my Action:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult New(string title = "", string content = "", string location = "")
    {
    //yada yada
    }
```

Doing this, params are mapped and the user can easily send  tags, etc.  I'm not turning ValidateInput off, and if I submit with a standard POST and remove the Stringify, it throws the error as expected.  Any good reason why JSONified data would skip validation?

**Edit** - More specific question: If JSONified data will pass HttpRequestValidation, how can we protect against the event where someone would intentionally mock a request to send JSON data instead of post params?  I haven't found a way to force the Action method to differentiate between params passed as JSON vs. those passed non-encoded.

Answer (score 1):

Got an answer for my question over on [asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/t/1682096.aspx/1?MVC3%20JSON%20Security) - See 2nd response.

Solution involves replacing the default ModelBinder.

Answer (score 0):

> Any good reason why JSONified data would skip validation?

JSON is encoded => so it ensures that what transits over the wire is *safe*. When you use `JSON.stringify` all dangerous characters are encoded.

Comment: Just so I understand then -- Couldn't one (maliciously) bypass HttpRequestValidation in MVC (3?) by mocking a request to include the params as stringified JSON?  The Controller Action would reflect out the params and be none the wiser?

Comment: Part of the reason for request validation is to prevent dangerous characters (such as < and &) from either being reflected back in HTML or being stored in the database. Though request validation is rudimentary at best (you should still HTML encode output provided from external sources), it's still worthwhile to implement, even when using JSON.